# FFMPEG: How to split a video *NOT* on a GOP boundary/Keyframe WITHOUT transcoding?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Using FFMPEG, how can you break a video up into equal length segments *THAT MAY OR MAY NOT start on KeyFrames?*

Assuming you are familiar with the *segment* format and the *break_non_keyframes* option, FFMPEG does *NOT* appear to do what I would expect (from what I read around...can no longer find the links).

```
ffmpeg -i ...  -f segment -break_non_keyframes 1 -segment_time 2 -c copy 2secs%03d.ts
```

Namely, create a segment that may in fact be longer than the desired segment, including the entire GOP as necessary.

For instance, assume a 3-frame GOP with a silly frame rate of 1 FPS with the following silly IBP cadence:

```
 01 02 03 11 12 13 21 22 23 31 32 33
  I  B  P  I  B  P  I  B  P  I  B  P
```

If I want to break it up into 2-second segments, would expect to see the following segments generated (frames in parens are not to be displayed in that segment):

```
01 02 03  (03 not displayed in this segment, only used for decoding)
01 02 03 11 (... 01 and 02)
11 12 13  (... 11 )
21 22 23  (... 23)
21 22 23 31 (...21 22)
31 32 33  (... 31)
```

As you can see, each segment will have extra frames in it, but given a start PTS and and end PTS, you can ALWAYS play/transcode just the segment by itself.

This is indeed wasteful of space (the sum of the segments will be MUCH larger than the original asset), but that's not the point here. The point is to have self-contained segments without transcoding.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to say that this isn't possible with the current segment muxer. The `break_non_keyframes` option is targeted at cases like HLS, where many players treat the segments as a continuous stream of packets, so reference data being split across multiple files isn't a problem.

I'm curious what your actual use-case here is. Where do you need fixed-length segments, each of which must be decodeable as a completely independent file? I doubt that most players would handle this the way you want them to; in the absence of a referenced picture, players will often display green or grey artifacts rather than dropping the frame.

Also, your IBP cadence is a bit misleading. Assuming that your frame numbers are display order, your frames would actually be ordered IPB/IPB/IPB/IPB in the stream.

If you actually do need this feature, it would be possible (but not entirely trivial) to implement in the segment muxer. You'd need to buffer every packet that comes in, discard the buffer every time you hit an IDR-frame, and write the buffer out to the next file you start writing.

Citation: I implemented the `break_non_keyframes` setting.

Comment: The IBP cadence was just made up as an example, I knew it was wrong, but just needed something simple. I need this so that I can break up a file into constant time-based segments, transcode individually and then either live-profile-DASH/HLS present, or recombine with the concat mux. In this way be able to better utilize servers (essentially allowing me to stop a transcode, move it to another machine and resume, or use all machines when there is no other asset available, etc). If I had control of the source, I would make sure the source file is well-formed. But sadly, I don't :-(

Comment: ...source ASSET...

Comment: Secondarily, is there some way to get the "-ss" and "-t" flags to preserve the PTS  fields? It appears that the "-ss" and "-t" flags perform the proper GOP inclusion, but they reset the PTS to be 0-based. Not even sure something like this is legal in a a boxed MPEG stream, TS OR MP4.

Answer (score 0):

When I run

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f segment -c copy -reset_timestamps 1 -segment_time 2 -break_non_keyframes 1 a%02d.mp4
```

and then play the output MP4 segments using ffplay, many of them play fine, despite the many error messages rolling by. Only the 2-second portion is played. A few play but with artifacts i.e. the keyframe hasn't been decoded. However, if I set the segment time higher to, say, 11, then all segments play as you would like, via ffplay. This is not the case for TS output. Also playback doesn't work well in a regular player like VLC.

Alternatively, if I create a segment using the template below

```
ffmpeg -ss N -t 2 -i input.mp4 -c copy aN.ts
```

Potplayer played this fine - just the 2 second part, error-free. ffplay played all muxed frames, error-free. VLC played only the 2 second segment but with glitches. In my test, 229 frames of a 30 fps video were muxed into the output.

tl;dr Different players don't behave the same with files containing frames with negative DTS/PTS.  What's your use case?

Comment: Indeed, the "-ss/-t" options work great: they do exactly what I mention above: adding extra "undisplayed" frames at the beginning and end in order to ensure correct playback (at the possible cost of initial black in the cut sequence). It is curious that the segment formatter doesn't do this also wi9th "segment_time" turned off.

Comment: Inability to play back is not a killer for me: I want to transcode each N-segment segment individually. Thus,the bunch of undisplayed frames at the beginning and end do not matter. Note that preserving PTS is actually very useful for me, for the obvious reason (which is why I did not use the reset_timestamps).

Comment: I'm doing live stream with video quality reducing ,to save bandwidth . I  notice you have extra parameter `reset_timestamps`